# Trouble Plotting in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having trouble getting anything to plot in PyCharm.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    plt.plot(x, y)
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3590, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2540, in gca
    return gcf().gca()
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1000, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 934, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 464, in new_figure_manager
    _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 441, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
    canvas_class = cast(type[FigureCanvasBase], _get_backend_mod().FigureCanvas)
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 280, in _get_backend_mod
    switch_backend(rcParams._get("backend"))  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "C:\Desktop\plot_project\IB\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 343, in switch_backend
    canvas_class = module.FigureCanvas
AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'. Did you mean: 'FigureCanvasAgg'
```

?

I have been messing with this all afternoon.  Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: OS, version of matplotlib and PyCharm?

Comment: Give this a look: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7670665042450-getting-error-using-matplotlib-while-running-with-console-

Comment: You may wanna upgrade your matplotlib version https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25269

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for the link.  That looks like it addresses my issue.  Ill have a closer look this evening.  I appreciate the help!